# Dividing a set of overlapping ranges into a set of non - overlapping ones

Tags: javascript, set, intervals, overlapping, range

I have an array of overlapping ranges:

```
var ranges = [{
    "from": 0,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "from": 50,
    "to": 200
}, {
    "from": 0,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "from": 70,
    "to": 200
}, {
    "from": 90,
    "to": 300
}];
```

I need to convert it into a set of non - overlapping ranges, i. e.:

```
var nonOverlapping = splitRanges(ranges);

/*
nonOverlapping = [{
    "from": 0,
    "to": 49
}, {
    "from": 50,
    "to": 69
}, {
    "from": 70,
    "to": 89
}, {
    "from": 90,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "from": 101,
    "to": 200
}, {
    "from": 201,
    "to": 300
}]
*/
```

I have made a function that does this (in JavaScript) but of course as you can see it works very slow, because it uses so called "naive approach":

```
function splitRanges(ranges) {
    var repeat, length, i, j;
    var rangeA, rangeB, intersection;
    do {
        repeat = false;
        length = ranges.length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            rangeA = ranges[i];
            for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
                rangeB = ranges[j];
                if (isIntersectingRanges(rangeA, rangeB)) {
                    repeat = true;
                    ranges.splice(i, 1);
                    intersection = splitRange(rangeA, rangeB);
                    while (intersection.length) {
                        ranges.push(intersection.shift());
                    }
                }
                if (repeat) break;
            }
            if (repeat) break;
        }
    } while (repeat);
}
```

Can someone help me to rewrite this, so it behaves the same way and does this faster than naive approach?

**EDIT:**

Algorithm should be able to keep track of ranges ids + correctly handle ranges where from == to:

```
var ranges = [{
    id: 1,
    from: 0,
    to: 100
}, {
    id: 2,
    from: 30,
    to: 30,
}, {
    id: 3,
    from: 0,
    to: 100
}, {
    id: 4,
    from: 90,
    to: 300
}];
```

Expected output is:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "from": 90,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "from": 90,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "from": 101,
    "to": 300
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "from": 0,
    "to": 29
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "from": 90,
    "to": 100
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "from": 0,
    "to": 29
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "from": 30,
    "to": 30
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "from": 31,
    "to": 89
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "from": 30,
    "to": 30
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "from": 30,
    "to": 30
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "from": 31,
    "to": 89
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces your requred results for the specified input:

```
function splitRanges (intervals) { 'use strict';
  // Create arrays of the from and to values, do not record duplicate values 
  for (var to = [], from = [], n, i = intervals.length; i--;) {
    if (to.indexOf (n = intervals[i].to) < 0)
      to.push (n);
    if (from.indexOf (n = intervals[i].from) < 0)
      from.push (n);
  }

  // Sort both arrays
  to.sort (function (a, b) { return a-b; });
  from.sort (function (a, b) { return a-b; });

  // Create new intervals array
  intervals = [];
  while (to.length)
    intervals.push ({
      from: from.shift (),
      to: from.length == 0 ? (from.push ((n = to.shift ()) + 1), n) :
          from[0] > to[0] ? from[1] - 1 : from[0] - 1
    });

  return intervals;
}
```

When the same numer appears as both a from and a to value then a "spurious" null range is produced. Don't know if this case can happen in your data or if the extra range is a problem

Comment: This is the problem, because algorithm should be able to handle ranges where (from === to)

Comment: Can you add to your example 1) a null interval from 60 to 60 and 2) another range from 200 to 230 and update your expected results

Comment: Yes, please look at the last section of the original question, I've placed example below "edit", there is a range 30..30, and expected result produced by my non - optimal solution.

Comment: I've made jsFiddle page that contains couple of functions that I used for splitting. Just past an array of ranges (as in my question description) into the text area and press "split!" button, second text area will contain split result. So this is exactly what I need and how I need it to work, just faster. Hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/tbtXz/

Comment: Any optimized version of this.?